# Openstack: How to make a VM to autostart

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I have deployed Openstack queens for testing purposes.

`nova --version
14.2.0`

I noticed that when I reboot a compute host, all VMs running on it turn into SHUTOFF state.
I tried to change this behaviour by editing flavor metadata. I have added CIM_VSSD_AutomaticStartupAction property and have set it to the "Always startup" value, but no changes occur.

Is there any way to autostart a VM when compute node starts up?

Comment: Which VM? Presumably they should all be already running on the other compute nodes.

Comment: https://www.linuxtopic.com/2017/09/instance-autostart.html

Comment: @MichaelHampton VM that's running on that particulat compute node.
I think a VM will not run on 2nd node after 1st node fail because there are a lot of complex conditions for it. First of all a common storage system is needed.
This is what I want but for older openstack version:
https://www.linuxtopic.com/2017/09/instance-autostart.html

Answer (score 1):

Edit vi `/etc/nova/nova.conf` and set this to `true`

```
resume_guests_state_on_host_boot=true
```

then restart nova service

```
systemctl restart openstack-nova-compute
```

Comment: Note that the setting needs to be set on the compute nodes, not on the control nodes.